# az group export Azure Firewall and restore issue

Tags: powershell, azure-cli

I have a pipeline that provisions my clients clients Firewall and all associated Resources. As part of that Pipeline, I am taking a backup of the Firewall and Rule Collections before release and if anything goes wrong, a YAML stage (via a condition) will use the two backup files and restore the Firewall and its Rule Collections to their last known good state.

In my PowerShell within the Pipeline, I used the following command to backup the Firewall:
`az group export --name "fw-rg" --resource-ids "/subscriptions/1234/resourceGroups/fw-rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/azureFirewalls/myFirewall" --skip-all-params`

And that creates a file, that on the surface looks fine. The Rule Collections Json also looks fine.

The problem arises on the restore. Rule Collections works fine, but the Firewall fails with an error complaining about `resourceGroup` is not allowed.

Inspecting the Json, I can see a recurring pattern as such:
`"firewallPolicy": {"id": "/subscriptions/1234/resourceGroups/fw-rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/firewallPolicies/myFirewallPolicy", "resourceGroup": "fw-rg"},`

Performing an Export Template via the Portal, `resourceGroup` isn't presented as part of that output:

`"firewallPolicy": {"id": "[parameters('firewallPolicies_myFirewallPolicy_externalid')]"}`

I've reviewed the command to [export](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/group?view=azure-cli-latest#az-group-export) and no argument stands out as a likely candidate to get the Json in a verbatim format like the Portal.

The command I am using to restore is:
`az deployment group create --name $jobName --resource-group $resourceGroup --template-file $BackupFileName`

Has anyone encountered this before where the export gives Json that isn't strictly valid for a restore and any suggestions?

The only option that I can think of, which is a hack is to replace "resourceGroup": "rg" in the Json with an empty string, but then I have to contend with the preceeding `,` on the `id` line.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually found the answer if anyone runs into this issue. There might be a bug in the `az` command?

If I run this command as we know, it returns `resourceGroup` in various elements of the Json, which is invalid:
`az group export --name "fw-rg" --resource-ids "/subscriptions/1234/resourceGroups/fw-rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/azureFirewalls/myFirewall" --skip-all-params`

using `--include-parameter-default-value` instead of `--skip-all-params` returns the param values at the top of the Json, but more importantly doesn't place the extra and in my opinion invalid `resourceGroup` element in the Json